# Inserting row into SQL table with some predefined values, and some from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert a row into a table called `"all_games"` using SQLite. I have the values `"game"` and `"money"` where `game` is an `integer` and `money` is a `string`, however the middle value `"players"` is the value that I don't have, so I want to get it from another table that contains it.

This is the SQL Query that I am currently using:

```
INSERT INTO all_games (game, ... , money)
    SELECT (12, players, \'100, 200\') FROM games WHERE id=2
```

Just to clarify, "12" and "100, 200" represent values that I already have, I just want to get `players` from another table.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to remove the second set of parentheses.

```
INSERT INTO all_games (game, players , money)
    SELECT 12, players, '100, 200' FROM games WHERE id=2
```